# Android - Notifications below separation line

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm wondering how can you draw a notification below the separation line that exists in the notifications panel. As you can see on this picture Google Now has their notification there. FB Messenger chat heads notification is also there. 
I've looked into the documentation and tried various combinations of Categories, Priority and Visibility with no success.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build the notification, set priority to [`PRIORITY_MIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_MIN).

Example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this )
        .setCategory( NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE )
        .setContentTitle( mNotificationTitle )
        .setPriority( Notification.PRIORITY_MIN )
        .setContentIntent( launchSettingsIntent )
        .setVisibility( Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC )
        .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_notification );
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. Well at least on my devices. Thank you for the reply regardless.

Comment: It works on my Nexus 6P, Nexus 7 and Nexus 5, all on Marshmallow. Which ones are your devices?

Comment: You're right, it was actually my mistake. It works! Thank you :)

Comment: Excellent news. Glad I was able to help!